# Sending Soap-Request with Umlaut to OTRS

Tags: xml, linux, oracle, soap, otrs

So, I am trying to make a SOAP-Request to OTRS on a CentOS Linux server.
Someone made a PL-SQL-Package in an Oracle Database for that and it works fine unless there is an Umlaut (Ü) in the data.

That's the error I get in the linux errorlog:

```
Feb 17 08:32:26 eotrs2 GenericInterfaceProvider-10[11317]: [Error][Kernel::GenericInterface::Debugger::DebugLog][Line:218]: DebugLog error:  Summary: Error deserializing message:not well-formed (invalid token) at line 1, column 528, byte 528 at /usr/lib64/perl5/vendor_perl/XML/Parser.pm line 187.  Data   : No data provided.
Feb 17 08:32:26 eotrs2 GenericInterfaceProvider-10[11317]: [Error][Kernel::GenericInterface::Debugger::DebugLog][Line:218]: DebugLog error:  Summary: Request could not be processed  Data   : Error deserializing message:not well-formed (invalid token) at line 1, column 528, byte 528 at /usr/lib64/perl5/vendor_perl/XML/Parser.pm line 187..
Feb 17 08:32:26 eotrs2 GenericInterfaceProvider-10[11317]: [Error][Kernel::GenericInterface::Debugger::DebugLog][Line:218]: DebugLog error:  Summary: Returning provider data to remote system (HTTP Code: 500)  Data   : Error deserializing message:not well-formed (invalid token) at line 1, column 528, byte 528 at /usr/lib64/perl5/vendor_perl/XML/Parser.pm line 187..
```

Before we had the PL/SQL-Package, we used a Perl Script on the same server were the OTRS-service is running using `SOAP::Lite`.
Activating the trace in this Perl-Script, I realized, that it just changes the Umlaut "Ü" in the XML-file I provide to "Ã�" in the SOAP-Request which obviously isn't right either.

`NLS_CHARACTERSET` on the Oracle DB is `AL32UTF8`. `NLS_LAN` of the `otrs`-User on the server is `German_Austria.utf8`

Any suggestions?

Comment: from @a.j. tawleed: There is no German_Austria.AL32UTF8 in linux. That is just a weird Oracle specific charset, but which is similiar enough to common UTF8, so that there usually is no problems

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a not really satisfying solution.

In the PL/SQL-procedure, I use

```
l_envelope := CONVERT(l_envelope, 'AL32UTF8', 'WE8ISO8859P1');
```

which means, that I convert it to ISO 8859-1. But that doesn't answer my question, why it wants this charset. We usually use UTF-8.

Answer (score 0):

Check all characterset settings, pre- and post- changes.

The error message in the OP suggests the problem lives within perl xml parser (and I'm no perl guy), but I thought I'd comment on Oracle's characterset conversion behavior. Obviously the database has a defined characterset, But the oracle client s/w also defines what characterset it thinks it is using. With the connection to the database, the charactersets are are automatically converted according to Oracle's NLS conversions. So a conversion happens depending on the client's characterset.

I'd assume the `German_Austria.utf8` to `AL32UTF8` conversion is occurring correctly. Look upstream for other possible conversions occurring before the data reaches this point.

btw - if the client and database are set to the *same* characterset, then no character conversion occurs. If the client characterset was really wrong, then the data in the database may not be correct (because there was no conversion). When the client characterset is then corrected (or on a different client with different characterset definition), the extracted data will look 'wrong' -- previously un-converted data now being converted.